# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory : [python script] inside php shell_exec [ AWS-Lambda]

Tags: php, python, aws-lambda

I am running PHP in a lambda function using a node.js wrapper.
This is the python code I am running inside my PHP code using shell_exec.

`shell_exec($bin_path .' '. __DIR__ . "/ffprobe_hosts.py " . $video_url);`

Inside ffprobe_hosts.py

```
 scene_ps = subprocess.Popen(("/usr/bin/ffprobe", 
                        "-show_frames",
                        "-of",
                        "compact=p=0", 
                        "-f",
                        "lavfi",
                        "movie=" + src_video + ",select=gt(scene\," + 
                         str(threshold) + ")"),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

And this is the error which I am getting

```
2018-05-04T10:26:54.021Z    a8bfb250-4f85-11e8-bea2-f1c1fe029cf0     
STDERR:     boundaries = extract_shots_with_ffprobe(sys.argv[1])
File "/var/task/3rdparty/ffprobe/ffprobe_hosts.py", line 30, in 
extract_shots_with_ffprobe
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In the error it is mentioned 'No such file or directory, I am not sure which directory there are mentioning.

Comment: We really need the full content of `ffprobe_hosts.py`, or the implementation of the `extract_shots_with_ffprobe()` function to come closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace tells you that your Python script fails at line 30 where you call a function `extract_shots_with_ffprobe(sys.argv[1])`. `sys.argv[1]` is the first command-line argument to your Python script, i.e. `$video_url`. So the value of that variable is not a path that points to an existing file on the file system.

Comment: I have uploaded ffprobe binary whose path is /var/task/ffprobe.So when i changed '/usr/bin/ffprobe' command  in subprocess to /var/task/ffprobe, that error disappeared.But still output of the shell_exec is empty.The video url consists of Aws S3 path.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `/usr/bin/ffprobe` to `/var/task/ffprobe` which is the ffprobe binary path fixed the error.